# How to run user input as R code in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to create a shiny application that has an input for writing some R function or Command, reads it through the ui.R then passes it to the server.R that executes that R command to display the results.

I spent hours searching about some example but couldn't find anything, I already know how to create Shiny apps using ui and server and pass the input values to server and work with them, but I have no idea if it's possible to create a shiny app like R where you can write the commands and return the results, any example or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Letting users run code in your app is bad practice, since it comes with great security risks. However, for development you might want to check [this function](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/runcode.html) from the shinyjs package by Dean Attali.

Example from the link:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)

  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      runcodeUI(code = "shinyjs::alert('Hello!')")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      runcodeServer()
    }
  )
```

---

Some examples of why it is not such a good idea to include when deploying your app:

Try the input:

```
shinyjs::alert(ls(globalenv()))
```

or

```
shinyjs::alert(list.files())
```

Comment: Thank you Florian this is very helpful, but only for javascript code? can i use it for R code?

Comment: It works for R code only. Try typing `print("This is definitely not JS code!")`, and check your console. `alert` is an R function from the shinyjs package. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find an alternative solution that doesn't require `shinyjs` -- wanted to restate Florian's concern that in general it is not a good thing (not secure) to let users run code in your Shiny app. Here is the alternative:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
      h3("Data (mtcars): "), verbatimTextOutput("displayData"),
      textInput("testcode", "Try filtering the dataset in different ways: ", 
           "mtcars %>% filter(cyl>6)", width="600px"), 
      h3("Results: "), verbatimTextOutput("codeResults"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    shinyEnv <- environment() 
    output$displayData <- renderPrint({ head(mtcars) })  # prepare head(mtcars) for display on the UI

    # create codeInput variable to capture what the user entered; store results to codeResults
    codeInput <- reactive({ input$testcode })
    output$codeResults <- renderPrint({
      eval(parse(text=codeInput()), envir=shinyEnv)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```