# R: user interactively supplies mathmatical function

Tags: r

I am developing an R script that numerically solves and plots 2 person simultaneous move non-cooperative games, where the user interactively supplies the player's payoff functions. Eventually this will be a shiny app, but for now I am using readline().  I am just wondering if there is a better way to have the user supply the payoff functions?

```
user_input <- readline(prompt="enter a function of x and y (e.g. x^2+y^2-x*y): ")
func_text <- paste0("as.function(alist(x=,y=,",user_input,"))")
the_func <- eval(parse(text=func_text))
print(paste0("the value of your function at (x,y)=(10,10) is: ",the_func(10,10)))
```

Bonus: how could I test that the supplied string-function is valid before eval?

Comment: I would give serious consideration to choosing a different way to get and parse user input. What's to stop the user inputting a line that wipes your hard drive?

Comment: @AllanCameron was going to say the same thing. It could be a (very) bad day..

Comment: @AllanCameron perhaps you should not put the code there, but say what it does. If someone runs it trying to find out, that would be very bad

Comment: @stevec good point. Modified :)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45347963/5783745

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the function definition to this solves the issue

```r
user_input <- "j"
while(!grepl("^([xy+/*-]|\\d)+$", user_input)) user_input <- readline(prompt="enter a function of x and y (e.g. x^2+y^2-x*y): ")
the_func <-  eval(parse(text=paste0("function(x,y) ",user_input)))
```

Following the comments by @AllanCameron and @stevec and the issues they raised it seems that input validation is a must that's what the while loop is there for.

Comment: I added ```\\^\\(\\)``` to allow for polynomial functions.  Cheers,

Comment: note that in R `**` <=> `^` , I'd suggest using this regex then `^([xy+/*^()-]|\\d)+$` @RichardMartin